# Dirac delta and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, dirac-delta-distributions

I want to know why is this equality true:
$$P(o)P(o') = \delta(o-o')P(o)$$
Where P is the projector operator

I could see that:

$$P(o)P(o') = |o\rangle\langle o|o'\rangle\langle o' | = |o\rangle\delta^{o'}_{o}\langle o'| = \delta^{o'}_{o} |o\rangle\langle o'|$$

Now from where came the dirac delta?

Answer (score 2):

You have not explained what is your Hilbert space you're working on, and so as-is, there isn't a way to tell whether a Kroenecker delta or dirac delta is appropriate.

For example: If you are dealing with an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and perhaps $P_{o}$ projects onto the position eigenket $| o \rangle$ of the 1D position operator $\hat{X}$ (the eigenkets are $\{ | x \rangle \}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ labelled by each position, and you're picking $x = o$). In this kind of a setting the dirac-delta normalization is appropriate. One way to understand why is that we need to be able to resolve the identity
$$
\int d x\; | x \rangle \langle x | = I \ .
$$
If you take each side of the above operator and apply it to some position eigenstate $| o \rangle$, you will be able to convince yourself that you need $\langle x | o \rangle = \delta(x - o)$ for the above resolution of the identity to make sense.